# Simplifying project set up with Docker

Tags: docker

There is a project which consists of two parts: front-end (React) and back-end (NodeJS, Express, MongoDB).
I have to setup Docker to `simplify project set up on local machines and eliminate environment inconsistencies`.

Could someone please explain me what does it usually mean? (I've checked Docker crash courses and know some stuff, but I don't really know what should be done in my case)

Does it mean that I have to move related to back-end code along with database to Docker containers? If so, then it would only simplify set up for Front-end developer, but not for the back-end dev?

Comment: Can you clarify "have to"?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply provide a **docker-compose.yml** file and clarify steps to build your services, beforehand you must create a **Dockerfile** for each of your services.

Sample **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "expose ports here"
    image: "image name related to MongoDB"
    environment:
      - "declare credintionals here"
    networks:
      - "in order to separate network visibility of backed and frontend you can declare different networks"

  backend:
    container_name: my_backend_service
    ports:
      - "expose ports here"
    build: "path to your service Dockerfile"
    environment:
      - "you can have your backend envs here"
    networks:
      - "same as your dbs network, but you can have two different networks one for db and one for *frontend* in order to separate network visibility"
    depends_on:
      - "This part declares service running priority for Docker, you should declare service names here. e.g. db"

  frontend:
    container_name: my_fortend_service
    ports:
      - "expose ports here"
    build: "path to your service Dockerfile"
    networks:
      - "same as your *backend*s network, this makes your frontend service can see only backend services"
    depends_on:
      - "This part declares service running priority for Docker, you should declare service names here"

  
networks:
    your network1:
    your network2:
```